# Возможно ли посмотреть запрос на сервер из приложения и ответ сервера в React Native

Tags: react-native

Я использую Android Studio и React Native init. Возможно ли просматривать, что приложение отправляет на сервер и что получает с сервера. Как, например, в консоли разработчика в Хроме. Как это правильно делать?